# En mi transicion desde docker-compose a Docker Swarm no encuentro un remplazo para el .env

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Despues de aprender docker-compose, me veo en la necesidad de usar Docker Swarm para desplegar Traefik.

`docker-compose` permite sustituir ciertas variables del `docker-compose.yml` desde un `.env` como en este caso:

`.env`

```
ACME_EMAIL=email.yourdomain.com
URL_TRAEFIK_DASHBOARD=traefik.yourdomain.com
HTTPD_AUTH=test:(hash)
```

`docker-compose.yml`  (version docker-compose)

```yaml
version: "3.3"

services:
  traefik:
    container_name: ${TRAEFIK_CONTAINER_NAME:-traefik}
    image: "traefik:${TRAEFIK_IMAGE_TAG:-latest}"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro" 
      - ".letsencrypt:/letsencrypt" # Create a letsencrypt dir within the folder where the docker-compose file is
    command:
      - "--log.level=DEBUG" # Verbose debug
      - "--api.insecure=true"
      - "--providers.docker=true"
      - "--providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false" # Do not expose containers by default
      # Define entrypoints
      - "--entryPoints.web.address=:80"
      - "--entrypoints.websecure.address=:443"
      # Letsencrypt for https
      # - "--certificatesresolvers.le.acme.caserver=https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.le.acme.email=${ACME_EMAIL}"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.le.acme.httpchallenge.entryPoint=web"
      #- "--certificatesResolvers.le.acme.tlschallenge=true" # Enable a tls challenge named "le"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.le.acme.httpchallenge=true" # Enable a http challenge named "le"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.le.acme.storage=/letsencrypt/acme.json" # Tell to store the certificate on a path under our volume
    labels:
      # Redirect 80 to 443 (force https everywhere)
      - "traefik.http.routers.https-redirect.entrypoints=web"
      - "traefik.http.routers.https-redirect.rule=hostregexp(`{any:.*}`)" 
      - "traefik.http.routers.https-redirect.middlewares=redirect-to-https"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.redirect-to-https.redirectscheme.scheme=https"
      
      # Traefic dashboard
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.rule=Host(`${URL_TRAEFIK_DASHBOARD}`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.service=api@internal"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.tls.certresolver=le"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.entrypoints=websecure"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.middlewares=authtraefik"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.authtraefik.basicauth.users=${HTTPD_AUTH}"

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: ${NETWORK:-reverse-proxy}
```

Esto funciona bien en este `docker-compose`.

Sin embargo ésto no es posible en Docker Swarm y cuando haces un depliegue con:

`docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml traefik`

las variables de entorno del `.env` no se leen y por lo tanto el stack falla o se despliega sin la configuracion.

He leido sobre `configs` y `secrets` y no concibo la forma de utilizarlos correctamente en la siguiente configuracion para Docker Swarm de Traefik:

`docker-compose.yml`  (version swarm)

```yaml
version: '3.3'

services:

  traefik:
    # Use the latest Traefik image
    image: traefik:v2.2
    ports:
      # Listen on port 80, default for HTTP, necessary to redirect to HTTPS
      - 80:80
      # Listen on port 443, default for HTTPS
      - 443:443
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints:
          # Make the traefik service run only on the node with this label
          # as the node with it has the volume for the certificates
          - node.labels.traefik-public.traefik-public-certificates == true
      labels:
        # Enable Traefik for this service, to make it available in the public network
        - traefik.enable=true

        # Use the traefik-public network (declared below)
        - traefik.docker.network=traefik-public

        # Use the custom label "traefik.constraint-label=traefik-public"
        # This public Traefik will only use services with this label
        # That way you can add other internal Traefik instances per stack if needed
        - traefik.constraint-label=traefik-public

        # admin-auth middleware with HTTP Basic auth
        # Using the environment variables USERNAME and HASHED_PASSWORD
        - traefik.http.middlewares.admin-auth.basicauth.users=${HTTPD_AUTH}

        # https-redirect middleware to redirect HTTP to HTTPS
        # It can be re-used by other stacks in other Docker Compose files
        - traefik.http.middlewares.https-redirect.redirectscheme.scheme=https
        - traefik.http.middlewares.https-redirect.redirectscheme.permanent=true
        

        # traefik-http set up only to use the middleware to redirect to https
        # Uses the environment variable DOMAIN
        - traefik.http.routers.traefik-public-http.rule=Host(`${URL_TRAEFIK_DASHBOARD}`)
        - traefik.http.routers.traefik-public-http.entrypoints=http
        - traefik.http.routers.traefik-public-http.middlewares=https-redirect

        # traefik-https the actual router using HTTPS
        # Uses the environment variable DOMAIN
        - traefik.http.routers.traefik-public-https.rule=Host(`${URL_TRAEFIK_DASHBOARD}`)
        - traefik.http.routers.traefik-public-https.entrypoints=https
        - traefik.http.routers.traefik-public-https.tls=true

        # Use the special Traefik service api@internal with the web UI/Dashboard
        - traefik.http.routers.traefik-public-https.service=api@internal

        # Use the "le" (Let's Encrypt) resolver created below
        - traefik.http.routers.traefik-public-https.tls.certresolver=le

        # Enable HTTP Basic auth, using the middleware created above
        - traefik.http.routers.traefik-public-https.middlewares=admin-auth
        
        # Define the port inside of the Docker service to use
        - traefik.http.services.traefik-public.loadbalancer.server.port=8080
    volumes:
      # Add Docker as a mounted volume, so that Traefik can read the labels of other services
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
      # Mount the volume to store the certificates
      - traefik-public-certificates:/certificates

    command:
      # Enable Docker in Traefik, so that it reads labels from Docker services
      - --providers.docker
      # Add a constraint to only use services with the label "traefik.constraint-label=traefik-public"
      - --providers.docker.constraints=Label(`traefik.constraint-label`, `traefik-public`)
      # Do not expose all Docker services, only the ones explicitly exposed
      - --providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false
      # Enable Docker Swarm mode
      - --providers.docker.swarmmode
      # Create an entrypoint "http" listening on address 80
      - --entrypoints.http.address=:80
      # Create an entrypoint "https" listening on address 443
      - --entrypoints.https.address=:443
      # Create the certificate resolver "le" for Let's Encrypt, uses the environment variable EMAIL
      - --certificatesresolvers.le.acme.email=${ACME_EMAIL}
      # Store the Let's Encrypt certificates in the mounted volume
      - --certificatesresolvers.le.acme.storage=/certificates/acme.json
      # Use the TLS Challenge for Let's Encrypt
      - --certificatesresolvers.le.acme.tlschallenge=true
      # Enable the access log, with HTTP requests
      - --accesslog
      # Enable the Traefik log, for configurations and errors
      - --log
      # Enable the Dashboard and API
      - --api
    networks:
      # Use the public network created to be shared between Traefik and
      # any other service that needs to be publicly available with HTTPS
      - traefik-public

volumes:
  # Create a volume to store the certificates, there is a constraint to make sure
  # Traefik is always deployed to the same Docker node with the same volume containing
  # the HTTPS certificates
  traefik-public-certificates:

networks:
  # Use the previously created public network "traefik-public", shared with other
  # services that need to be publicly available via this Traefik
  traefik-public:
    external: true
```

Un workarround es utilizar `docker-compose config` y pasarlo a un archivo o leer el stdin desde `docker stack deploy`:

`docker-compose config | docker stack deploy -c - traefik`

Esto en la mayoria de los casos funciona sin problemas, en el mio se produce un error:

```
networks.traefik-public Additional property name is not allowed
```

El `docker-compose.yml` tiene una red externa definida como:

```yaml
traefik-public:
    external: true
```

Y la salida de `docker-compose config` produce el siguiente resultado indeseado:

```yaml
 . . .
networks:
      traefik-public: null
. . .
```

¿Cómo puedo configurar este docker compose de forma dinámica utilizando docker `config` o `secrets`? ya que desde un archivo .env no esposible.

No deberia tener que "hardcodear" mi configuracion en el docker-compose.

La unica solucion que he encontrado es hacer `export` de todas las variables de entorno que necesito antes de desplegar el stack.

Answer (score 1):

SOLUCION:

1. por preferencia personal sustituir el label que contiene el passwd en plaintext por un label que apunta a un archivo y pasarle un `docker secret`.

- Sustituimos:

`traefik.http.middlewares.admin-auth.basicauth.users`=`${HTTPD_AUTH}`

por

`traefik.http.middlewares.admin-auth.basicauth.usersfile`=`/run/secrets/USERS`

- Añadimos los USERS.secret (archivo que contiene lo mismo que `HTTPD_AUTH`) desde una ruta conveniente ej.: `.secrets/USERS.secret`

**IMPORTANTE añadir .secrets a .gitignore para no preservarlo en nuestro control de versiones.**

- En nuestro `docker-compose.yml` debemos definir los secrets, hay mas formas pero en mi caso es conveniente desde un archivo:

```yaml
version: '3.3'

secrets:
  # secret name also used to name the file exposed within the container
  USERS:
     # path on the host
    file: "./.secrets/USERS.secret"
```

- añadimos los secrets que necesitamos a los servicios que queremos:

```yaml
. . .
services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:v2.2
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    secrets: 
        - USERS
    deploy:
. . .
```

2. Crea un archivo auxiliar `deploy.sh` para facilitar la ejecucion del siguiente script:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
export $(cat .env) > /dev/null 2>&1; 
docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml ${1:-STACK_NAME}
```

- el .env se parsea sin excepciones extrañas sin expresiones regulares o casos especiales.
- los errores que producen los `#comentarios` del `.env` en `cat .env` se canalizan desde `stderr` a `stdin` (`2>&1`) y no llenamos la consola de flood.
- podemos definir `STACK_NAME` en nuestro `.env`
- podemos pasarle el `stack_name` manualmente.

3. `. deploy.sh <stack_name>` (stack_name opcional)